# Changing the source for an image makes its width/height zero on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, coffeescript

When I select an image from a variety of choices already on the server, and then click on the canvas an image will be drawn on the spot clicked.

The problem I'm having is that on the first click the image's height and width are zero and nothing is drawn.  On the second click, it works perfectly, and it continues to work perfectly until I select a different image and then the 1st click doesn't work again.

I'm guessing that since it only happens when selecting a new source for the image that this has something to do with the image not have been loaded yet when the width and height are set.

Here is the code:

*where source is a string example: "sample/ball.png", "sample/dog.png"*

**Javascript**:

```
  this.image_object = new Image();
  this.image_object.src = source;
  this.width = this.image_object.width;
  this.height = this.image_object.height;
```

**Coffeescript**:

```
@image_object = new Image()
@image_object.src = source
@width = @image_object.width
@height = @image_object.height
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.  This code is called only when a seperate button is clicked, so the image can not be called on page load.

**EDIT:**

I also want to mention that manually setting the image width/height "new Image(52,52)" still takes two clicks since the image is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want to load all of the images right after the page loads.  I use the following function for this:

```
  loadImages = (fxDone) ->
    doneCount = 0 
    total = imageURLs.length
    for imageURL in imageURLs
      imageName = imageURL.slice(0, imageURL.lastIndexOf("."))
      images[imageName] = new Image()
      images[imageName].onload = ->
        doneCount++
        if doneCount == total
          fxDone()
      images[imageName].src = imageURL
```

Somewhere outside of this function, `imageURLs` should be defined as a list of, well, image URLs.  And `images` should be initialized as an empty map.  I call this in the `onload` handler, and pass a function `fxDone` to get things started that are dependent on the images being loaded.

Another option is to load on click if the image is not yet loaded.  Note that this will be a bit slower to respond to the first click.  I would do this as follows:

```
if @images[source]?
  @width = @images[source].width
  @height = @images[source].height
else
  @images[source] = new Image()
  @images[source].onload = ->
    @width = @images[source].width
    @height = @images[source].height
  @images[source].src = source
```

Outside of this, `@images` should be initialized to an empty map.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, That's because the image hasn't been loaded into the DOM when the .width attribute is called. All you did is set the source. That's why it works after the button is clicked. You have to load the image into the DOM before a width can be determined.

Are you using a framework?

If not, this will probably help.
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108392

Comment: The example you linked to doesn't work for me.  The alert message I get is undefined by undefined for width/height

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a jQuery tag, I would use jQuery to do this.  Indeed, the issue is that the width and height are not known until the image is loaded.  Do this instead:

```
var container = this;
var theImg = $('<img/>')
    .appendTo($(container))
    .load(function() { 
        $(container).width(theImg.width()).height(theImg.height());
    })
    .attr('src', source);
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me.  It still took two clicks.  Is @image_object "this" is your example?

Comment: No; in your sample code, you're setting `this.width` and `this.height`; I don't know what `this` is in your sample code, but that's what my `this` is trying to be.

Comment: Using the correct this still, did not solve the issue.  I still got a width and height of 0.

Comment: I left out an important detail; the image may also need to be included in the DOM before it has a width and height as @polyhedron mentioned.  See my updated code which also places the newly created `img` in a container.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Unfortunately, your latest solution isn't working either.